# Prevent creation of <img src="data:image/png;base64 ..." > during copy paste

Tags: php, html, image, base64

When I use `Ctrl+C` on an image on my PC and `Ctrl+V` on an WYSIWUG editor, it creates an image converted via base64. But this changes from browser and the OS I use.

What I want is to know if there are some ways to prevent it via Javascript before the `Ctrl+V` has effect?

Comment: Right click -> copy image location

Answer (score 0):

Right Click and choose save image as option. The dialog should have a few options on the format of your image that you can choose.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this configuration:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        theme: "advanced",
        plugins: "paste",
        paste_preprocess: function (plugin, args) {                
            if (args.content.startsWith("<img")){
                // replace copied text with empty string
                args.content = '';   
            }
        },
        ...
    });
```